# Custom controls in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, winforms, com, custom-controls, powerpoint

I managed to create a controls library for PPT. I created 6 Controls:

```
ButtonTestDispatch (inherits Windows.Forms.Button / AutoDispatch)
ButtonTestDual (inherits Windows.Forms.Button / AutoDual)
LabelTestDispatch (inherits Windows.Forms.Label / AutoDispatch)
LabelTestDual (inherits Windows.Forms.Label / AutoDual)
PanelTestDispatch (inherits Windows.Forms.Panel / AutoDispatch)
PanelTestDual (inherits Windows.Forms.Panel / AutoDual)
```

[Why Dual/Dispatch => just for the tests...]

I try to Add the controls into a slide using `AddOLEObject()`. I managed to correctly register the library.

**Problem:**

The controls are displayed on the slide but they are displayed as Red crosses (like GDI+ crashed displays).

[image]

Does anyone know if what i am trying to do is possible? How to correct it?

Comment: Please format your questions accordingly. Don't just copy them from a mailing list mail and paste here.

Comment: I didn't... I formatted it on stackoverflow. It seems in good shape on my screen. What do you see ?

Comment: Every line had a `<br />` tag on the end of it, that's why I thought you copied it from an email. But nevermind, it was removed

Comment: Sorry, it is my first post here. I did add the <br/> because the usual return carrier didn't work... I can't see the <br/> on the page right now. I can try to remove them but i think it is gonna break the format...

Comment: Nevermind, I already corrected that. Focus on the question now! :)